# how make loop can addiction by values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm newbie, I have values of array like this :

`$array = [0.25, 0.1667, 0.1667, 0.1667, 0.125, 0.125] ;`

I want make addiction like this on looping:

```
$array = [
    0 => 0.25, 
    1 => 0.25 + 0.1667, 
    2 => 0.25 + 0.1667 + 0.1667, 
    3 => 0.25 + 0.1667 + 0.1667 + 0.1667, 
    4 => 0.25 + 0.1667 + 0.1667 + 0.1667 + 0.125, 
    5 => 0.25 + 0.1667 + 0.1667 + 0.1667 + 0.125 + 0.125
];
```

then result of looping and arrays can be :

`$array = [0.25, 0.416667, 0.58333, 0.75, 0.875, 1];`

please help me, how make a looping (for, while, etc... ) and change to array, thanks for help!

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We expect you to show some actual initial effort here - show something that you tried, and explain what exactly the problem with it was. Please don't come here to get the absolute basics explained to you (_"how make a looping (for, while, etc..."_), that's what beginner's tutorials & books are for.

Comment: Also fix the spelling and grammar in the title ("how make loop can addiction by values in array"); that's not English.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [0.25, 0.1667, 0.1667, 0.1667, 0.125, 0.125] ;
$output = [];
$temp = 0;
foreach($array as $key=>$val) {
  $output[$key] =  $val + $temp;
  $temp = $output[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
$array = [0.25, 0.1667, 0.1667, 0.1667, 0.125, 0.125];
$temp = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    $temp += $val;
    $array[$key] = $temp;
}
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and add for every iteration the current to the last value.

```
$array = [0.25, 0.1667, 0.1667, 0.1667, 0.125, 0.125] ;

$res = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item) {
    $carry[] = $item + end($carry);
    return $carry;
}, []);

print_r($res);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.25
    [1] => 0.4167
    [2] => 0.5834
    [3] => 0.7501
    [4] => 0.8751
    [5] => 1.0001
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/76HCU)